# How can I compare variables and set a variable to new text found in one of the variables in c#

Tags: c#, string, variables, compare

I need to compare files found in a directory with another directory and print the files new files found in a directory into the console. I have it setup so it takes the files and assigns it to a variable. The other directory is assigned to another variable. How can I print the new data in one of the variables to command prompt?
The language I am using is c#.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Write the path of the old file folder: ");
            string path = Console.ReadLine();
            listFilesFromDirectory(path);


            Console.Write("Write the path of the new file folder: ");
            string pathTwo = Console.ReadLine();
            listFilesFromDirectoryMore(pathTwo);
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue:");
            Console.Read();
        }

        static void listFilesFromDirectory(string workingDirectory)
        {
            // get a list of files in a directory, 
            // based upon a path that is passed into the function
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(workingDirectory);
            foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
            {
                // use the foreach loop to go through the entire 
                // array one element at a time write out 
                // the full path and file name of each of the 
                // elements in the array
                Console.WriteLine(filePath);
                string oldfile = (filePath);

            }
        }

        static void listFilesFromDirectoryMore(string workingDirectoryTwo)
        {
            // get a list of files in a directory, 
            // based upon a path that is passed into the function
            string[] filePathsTwo = Directory.GetFiles(workingDirectoryTwo);
            foreach (string filePathTwo in filePathsTwo)
            {
                // use the foreach loop to go through the entire 
                // array one element at a time write out 
                // the full path and file name of each of the 
                // elements in the array
                Console.WriteLine(filePathTwo);
                string newfile = (filePathTwo);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so now you have two files lists of files in two folders like lstFilesA and lstFilesB ?

Comment: I have a variable for Folder A and one for Folder B

Comment: what's inside these variable ? show us your code

Comment: https://pastebin.com/samKTHLs

Comment: is there anything i can do to compare the variables

Comment: You created two local variable filePaths  and filePathsTwo in two seperate methods. So you cant compare it each other to get the differences. Search for "C# Variable Scopes"

Comment: So i combine the two methods i can compare them?

Comment: What exactly are you comparing? file names?

Comment: I compare the files names and if there are new file names it prints them out into the console\

Comment: How would you know  if they are "new"?

Comment: The new code is here https://pastebin.com/sY6UDE1m

Comment: I would know if they are new because they aren't in one of the variables

Comment: One variable has it one doesn't

Comment: So you want to list all the file names in one directory that are NOT in another directory?

Comment: Exactly. That is what I am trying to do. I did not know how to word it.

Comment: To print out which file in filePaths but not in filePathsTwo : Loop filePaths then use list's build-in method Exist() to check, if filePathsTwo.Exists(*loop data here*) is false -> print *loop data here* out

Comment: Will this work for multiple new files?

Comment: I do not understand how to combing the two methods together to get the "new" files

Comment: Sorry, my mentioned Exist() method is wrong, it is Contains(), see my Answer bellow. Note : I just wrote it without test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Write the path of the old file folder: ");
            string pathA = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Write the path of the new file folder: ");
            string pathB = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue:");

            List<string> folderA = new List<string>();
            foreach (string filePath in Directory.GetFiles(pathA))
            {
                folderA.Add(Path.GetFileName(filePath));
            }

            List<string> folderB = new List<string>();
            foreach (string filePath in Directory.GetFiles(pathB))
            {
                folderB.Add(Path.GetFileName(filePath));
            }

            Console.Write("New files in folder" + pathA + " : ");
            Print(folderA, folderB);

            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------");

            Console.Write("New files in folder" + pathB + " : ");
            Print(folderB, folderA);

            Console.Read();
        }

        static void Print(List<string> lstA, List<string> lstB)
        {
            foreach (string fileName in lstA)
            {
                if (!lstB.Contains(fileName))
                {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine(fileName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try the program out!

Comment: It shows all the files in the folders and not the new ones

Comment: Edit   **Console.Write("New files in folder" + filePathsTwo + " : ");**   to 
  **Console.Write("New files in folder" + pathTwo + " : ");**

Comment: Ok I will try it out

Comment: As I said, I wrote without test, so you need understand the idea to solve you problems, not just copy and run it without understand nothing.

Comment: I think there is a problem ! Directory.GetFiles(path) get full file's Path, not just file's Name. So you need to get the file's name from file' path by **Path.GetFileName(filePath)**

Comment: You are right. I am debugging and will try your solution

Comment: Yes it is now working fully! Once again thank you for your help.